# change a field in a line from textfile, storing into array than re-writing into a file

Tags: c++, arrays, stream

My program takes in two parameters, first parameter is name to be changed, and 2nd parameter is the name to which change it.

After execution, my textfile is missing the the second line, which suppose to be changed from May to MayMay. I'm not sure if my `if else` statement has problems or `while(!file.fail)` has problems.

This is my original textfile.

```
user;   pass;   1234; John;     1111
user1;  pass1;  2345; May;      2222
user2;  pass2;  3456; Mary;     3333
user3;  pass3;  4567; Andy;     4444
hr;     hr;     5678; Jonathan; 5555
admin;  admin;  6789; Aili;     6666
user10; pass10; 7890; eggy;     9999
user11; pass11; 9807; Mary;     7777
```

This is my output textfile after program execute.

```
user;   pass;   1111;  John;

user2;  pass2;  3333;  Mary;
user3;  pass3;  4444;  Andy;
hr;     hr;     5555;  Jonathan;
admin;  admin;  6666;  Aili;
user10; pass10; 9999;  eggy;
user11; pass11; 7777;  Mary;

        pass11; 7777;  Mary;
```

This is my code:

```
bool Employee::changeName(string nnn, string mmm)
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream file("login1.txt"); // to open the file
    string name, empty, empty2, empty3, empty4; // fusername is use to store the first parameter in textfile,empty is use to store the rest of the line after the ';'
    string store[100]; // initialize a array to store textfile contents

    while (!file.fail()) // loop if file didn't fail
    {   
        getline(file, empty, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
        getline(file, empty2, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
        getline(file, empty3, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
        getline(file, name, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
        getline(file, empty3); // use line end as delimiter, and to skip the rest of the information
        string add = ""; //initialize add string to nothing when it loops

        if(name != nnn) // to check if the username in textfile do not match the user input name
        {
            add += empty + ';' + empty2 + ';' + empty3 + ';' + name + ';' + empty4; // adds back the username and rest of the line together back    
            store[i] = add; // store into an array
            cout << "i is: " << i << endl; // debugging.
            cout << "store array[] = " << store[i] << endl; // debugging..
            i++;
        }
        else if(name == nnn)
        {
            add += empty + ';' + empty2 + ';' + empty3 + ';' + mmm + ';' + empty4; // adds back the name and rest of the line together back 
            store[i];
            cout << "i is: " << i <<endl; // debugging.
            cout << "store array[] = " << store[i] << endl; // debugging..
            i++;
        }
        else{}  
    }

    remove("login1.txt"); //remove the textfile
    ofstream pwd2_file ; // initilize a outputstream textfile
    pwd2_file.open("login1.txt"); // create a new file call login1.txt

    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)//for loop to store store[] array into login1.txt
    {
        pwd2_file << store[x] << endl; // storing into textfile
    }
    pwd2_file.close(); // close the output stream
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem causing the empty line is that when you replace the name in the else-if statement you have the lines

```
add += empty+';'+empty2+';'...
store[i];
```

I'm guessing that should be

```
store[i] = add;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading into `empty3` twice per loop while leaving `empty4` empty:

```
getline(file, empty, ';');
getline(file, empty2, ';');
getline(file, empty3, ';');  // <--- here
getline(file, name, ';');    //     
getline(file, empty3);       // <--- and here (this is supposed to be empty4, right?)
```

Then you've got a statement with no effect (already pointed out by Chad Campbell):

```
store[i];
```

And finally, an incorrect condition: `while(!file.fail())` - you enter the last iteration when the stream is still good - you've read all the data but not yet attempted to read past the end which would put the stream in bad state - next reads fail but you don't check it and silently re-use the data from the previous iteration.

Always use input operations in some boolean context (like `while(getline(...))`, for example) or at least check the stream *after* you attempted a read. In your case, something like this:

```
while (true)
{   
    getline(file, empty, ';');
    getline(file, empty2, ';');
    getline(file, empty3, ';');
    getline(file, name, ';');
    getline(file, empty3);
    if (!file) break;

    // do stuff with data
}
```